# How to cut or truncate any integer column value - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

From a pandas dataframe some values are too large, so the idea is to cut the numbers for example if I have 150 000 round integer number as a value in a column I would like to delete the last 3 integers (000) -> from 150 000 to 150.

Dataframe:

```
cut_nums = [15000,1200,500,7000]

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(cut_nums, columns = ['Col_val'])
```

Output:

```
    Col_val
0   15000
1   1200
2   500
3   7000
```

Attempt to solve it:

```
data_frame['Col_val'] = np.where((data_frame.Col_val < 100000), round(Col_val), data_framef.Col_val)
```

There are other functions that manipulate float numbers(Such as: round(), cut(), int()) but not integer numbers.
However, the basic idea is to find all those numbers that have too many integers and cut them/truncate them.

Desired outptut:

```
    Col_val
0   15
1   12
2   50
3   70
```

Example two cut all to three integers:

```
    Col_val
0   150
1   120
2   500
3   700
```

Example two cut all to one integers:

```
0   1
1   1
2   5
3   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure of the efficacy but try regex and convert back to integer. You can always vary the numeral in the curly brackets.

```
data_frame['Col_val'].astype(str).str.extract('(^\d{2})').astype(int)
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. even though I made sure I've convert the whole column values to integer (.astype(int)) still this is the error I get. probably it's because some of the values or less than 4 integers from deafult. Doesn't seem to be the most efficient way. If I get rid of your codes last part of astype(int) it does it's job but it converts the ones with less than 4 integers to NaN

Comment: @jcaliz          
  output: 0,   1000,  5000,  NaN,  NaN,  1500 original df: 10000, 
 50000,  4,   9,  15000. Still the same issue seems to be messing with the length of a string that is already less than 4.  Probably len() with iloc/loc with a condition is the solution? Or just a condition that ignores those rows that > 4

Comment: what about: `data_frame['Col_val'].astype(str).str.extract('(^\d{,2})').astype(int)`